# Efficient way of explicitly writing Sylow groups of $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

I am trying to write explicitly the Sylow 5-subgroups of the symmetric group $S_5$. Using the properties of the cardinal of the set of Sylow subgroups, I have come to the conclusion that there must be $6$ Sylow 5-subgroups. I know one of them is $H_1=\langle (1,2,3,4,5)\rangle$ and the other five subgruops should also be generated by a cycle of order 5. My problem is that $H_1$ contains several cycles of order 5 and I would like to write the rest of Sylow 5-subgroups making sure that I do not make the mistake of writing two subgroups that are actually equal but just "look different" because the generator is different.

The only way I can think of for approaching this problem is writing all of the elements of each subgroup and making sure that they are all different, but this is not very efficient. I was wondering if there might be some an **efficient** way to do this or a **clever way of choosing the generator** of each subgroup so as to make sure that all subgroups are different.

Any trick you can come up with would be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not that complicated. You just need to write down the $5$-cycles of $S_5$.

Comment: @the_fox That's fine for $S_5$, but the question is interesting for general $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's generalize to $S_p$.

The map $\sigma\mapsto\langle\sigma\rangle$ from $p$-cycles to Sylow $p$-subgroups in $S_p$ is a $(p-1)$-to-$1$ map, since every such subgroup has $p-1$ generators. There are $p!/p=(p-1)!$ elements of order $p$, so there are $(p-2)!$ Sylow subgroups.

Sylow theorems says the Sylow subgroups are conjugate, which by orbit-stabilizer means they correspond to cosets of the normalizer of one of them. If we let $\sigma=(12\cdots p)$ then any $\tau$ which fixes adjacent numbers but no others cannot be in the normalizer (consider how conjugation affects cycle types), so in paticular $S_{p-2}$ is a set of coset representatives for $N_{S_p}(\langle\sigma\rangle)$. Thus, the set of $p$-cycles $\pi$ fixing $p-1$ and $p$ form an irredundant list of generators for the $p$-Sylows.

Answer (score 3):

Let's work in any general $S_p$ and look for Sylow $p$-subgroups, which must all be generated by $p$-cycles.  Any such subgroup must have a unique element that permutes $1$ to $2$.  Use that element to generate the subgroup, and (written in cycle notation) each permutation of the remaining elements gives you a unique subgroup.

Thus, $\sigma = (1~2~\tau)$ generates a unique Sylow subgroup where $\tau$ is any permutation of $\{3, 4, \ldots p \}$.  This also demonstrates that there are $(p-2)!$ such subgroups.

Comment: I was typing a similar description. Thanks for saving me a bit of work. +1. It is, of course, equivalent to runway44's answer (+1 there also), but may be a little bit more accessible to an absolute beginner. Not necessarily any longer to someone exposed to Sylow subgroups.